# How to find count of all records in type inside index elasticsearch java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I have started working recently working on **elasticsearch** in Java platform. I wanted to find out count of all documents inside type in specific index with help of Java without fetching all records.
  Found following ways to do this not sure which will be better choice.

- `CountRequestBuilder` (Deprecated in recent releases)
- prepareSearch with `setsize` set to 0.
- Using `SearchType.COUNT` while creating search.

  Little confused with above options. is there any better solution ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a simple aggregation over the field **_type**. Here is a JSON equivalent:

```
{   
"aggs": {
    "my_terms": {
       "terms": {
         "field": "_type"
       }
     }
  }
}
```